# Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream?

Tags: java, android

Considering the code below, when i call foo1() then foo2(), everything is good. But when i call them together, i randomly get the error:

- Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

The error is sometimes related to foo1 and sometimes foo2. However after each error, the related method stops working but after a few seconds resumes. How to solve the issue?

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
//some code including onCreate method
private void foo1() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            while (true){
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrlByGet(url1);
                myList.add(jsonObject);
                url1 = getNewUrl(url1);                                             
                if(!jsonObject.getJSONObject("pagination").has("next_url"))
                    break;                                                 
            }  catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }).start();
}
private void foo2() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            while (true){
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrlByGet(url2);
                myList.add(jsonObject);
                url2 = getNewUrl(url2);                         
                if(!jsonObject.getJSONObject("pagination").has("next_url"))
                    break;                                                 
            }  catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }).start();
}
}

public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrlByGet(String url) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

here is the log:

```
12-27 11:48:46.076: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 first pack
12-27 11:48:46.201: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 second pack
12-27 11:48:46.771: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 third pack
12-27 11:48:47.386: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 first pack
12-27 11:48:47.391: I/System.out(20738): E/Buffer Error(6888): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
12-27 11:48:47.681: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 second pack
12-27 11:48:47.731: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 fourth pack
12-27 11:48:48.651: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 fifth pack
12-27 11:48:48.656: I/System.out(20738): E/Buffer Error(6888): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
12-27 11:48:50.826: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 third pack
12-27 11:48:50.836: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 fourth pack
12-27 11:48:50.856: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 fifth pack
12-27 11:48:50.891: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 sixth pack
12-27 11:48:50.891: I/System.out(20738): got foo2 seventh pack
12-27 11:48:52.686: I/System.out(20738): E/Buffer Error(6888): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
12-27 11:48:52.696: I/System.out(20738): got foo1 sixth pack
```

Comment: Anytime you get an exception, post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that you are using threads, which will get executed randomly, hence sometimes you get error in foo1 and other times in foo2.

In your run() methods, you loop continuously because of `while(true){}`

So lets say your foo1 starts executing, it goes into while loop, and calls getJSONFromUrlByGet(), which in turn will read till end of data and then closes the stream. See `is.close()`

But because of the static instance, 'is' is shared amongst all the all instances of the class. Hence, when getJSONFromUrlByGet() gets called again, the stream is already closed and hence the exception.

Comment: I edited the question and added the InputStream declaration. It's a static field in JSONParser class. However i don't think the problem comes from threads neither from is.close() because each while loop uses a new instance of JSONParser class hence a new input stream. By the way, the while loop breaks whenever is needed. it's not infinite.

Comment: can you try without static?

Comment: After removing static and turning the input stream to a field, the problem solved. Now my app is considerably one step forward. Many thanks to Rusheel Jain :)

Comment: thanks.
Declaring it static was making the same instance available for all of your class objects (static variable property)

Comment: I recommend you edit your answer and clearly explain about what you mentioned in comments on trying without static. This will help others get the answer quicker and more clear. Thanks again.